# c++ about operator overloading

Tags: c++

why

> The assignment operator must be a
>   non-static member function
>
> operator(), operator[], and operator->
>   must also be implemented as non-static
>   member functions.

for example

```
class IntList
{
private:
    int m_anList[10];

public:
    int& operator[] (const int nIndex);
};

int& IntList::operator[] (const int nIndex)
{
    return m_anList[nIndex];
}
```

this is subscript overloading. It only can be overloaded by using member function.
It cannot be overloaded by using friend function,
such as,

```
class Cents
{
private:
    int m_nCents;

public:
    Cents(int nCents) { m_nCents = nCents; }

    // Overload -cCents
    friend Cents operator-(const Cents &cCents);
};

// note: this function is not a member function!
Cents operator-(const Cents &cCents)
{
    return Cents(-cCents.m_nCents);
}
```

Comment: Show some us some code on how you think it might work. The best answers show-and-tell what the OP is trying to do and has tried up until the time the question was posted.

Comment: Why? because its the C++ definition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these operators (`operator=`, `operator()`, `operator[]`, and `operator->`) gets invoked on an instance of the class of which you define these operators as non-static member functions!

static member or non-member functions are like free functions. They don't get invoked on an instance of the class.

For example, if you make `operator[]` a static function, then you don't have `this` pointer inside it, then the function would not know which instance it is supposed to act on:

```
//illegal code
static int& IntList::operator[] (const int nIndex)
{
    return m_anList[nIndex]; //of which instance this `m_anList` is a member?
}
```

Comment: but I put "friend" identifier in that class. ?

Comment: @user658266: the `friend` keyword only tells that the function can access the private members of the class. it doesn't automatically have `this` pointer in it. That is, if the function is `friend`, then you can write `obj.privateMember` inside the function definition. Note it's accessing private member, but it still needs to know `obj` so that it can know which object it's acting on!

Comment: I think OP wonders why it can't be a free function: `int& operator[](IntList&, size_t);` At least this is what people are asking in what seem to be duplicates of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

They have exactly one parameter because the assignment operator is a binary operator.  The left hand side is the object being changed, the right hand side is the object being assigned to the left hand side.

It's non-static because static member functions aren't specific to a single instance of that class, they're general to the whole class. It doesn't make sense to do assignment on anything but a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operator (If i am not wrong you mean copy constructor internally) is instance specific. I.e. Content of each object must be copied/copyable. So it must be non static. Static functions have a more global role so it cannot take care of specific instances. 
In short if you have a requirement to affect the functionality of all your instances then only static members (variables and methods) must be used. As in a counter to hold the number of currently available objects count.

Now for only one parameter - It is because you need to create a copy ofsomething (eventhough it is a class object which has multiple data types internally, It is a single object only)

Similarly (),[] and -> are instance specific.

Comment: I doubt assignment operator equals to copy constructor.

Comment: Consider class MyClass{....}; MyClass obj1(10); MyClass obj2 = obj1; Now what it means here is Obj2 is simliar to obj1 (i.e. the states are copied)...... Assignment operator is not one to one a copy contructor but may utilize it internally. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)